# How to open new Safari window on primary display

Tags: safari, display, fullscreen

I am using a monitor as my second display for my MacBook Air. I have Netflix fullscreen on my second display. Whenever I want a Safari window on my primary display, I have to go to the second display, create a new window, and drag it over to my primary display. this disrupts Netflix, as I have to click to leave full screen then put it back to fullscreen.

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

"active" the primary display and run this applescript

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document at end of documents with properties {URL:"about:black"}
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: This works, although the menubar cuts off a few pixels of Safari's top bar. I always have to drag it down. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've tested it. work fine but no cuts off by menubar,sorry about that